# HABTM logic needed

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have posts and tags and posts_tags tables.

I want to list tags in post on all posts. e.g

```
1 | Hello world | (hello,world,is,generic)
```

Getting all posts then watching on posts_tags for related tags and add them to posts.

So how can I get foreach post related tags, from tag table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be retrieving related tags automatically when doing find on Posts. unless you have set the recursive property to 0 or -1. try increasing the value of recuresive